# Removing rules attribute from asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, gridview

i have a gridview i wish to style without borders but whenever i use the control asp.net adds in the attribute rules="all" i've tried overriding in on the control like so:

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" rules="none">`

but this doesn't work either

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Specify `GridLines="None"` in the `asp:GridView` tag or in your code-behind:

```
myGridView.GridLines = GridLines.None
```

Additionally, if you have time, it's worth looking into the [ASP.NET 2.0 CSS Friendly Control Adapters 1.0](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/), which produce much cleaner markup than the default controls output.

Answer (score 3):

try the gridlines property, set it to none.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answers

> The rules attribute specifies which parts of the inside borders that
>   should be visible.

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_rules.asp
The rules attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 9+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

The  rules attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by applying inline style to Gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" style="border-width:0;" runat="server">
```